# Python tkinter: Janela funciona perfeitamente, mas não fecha após executar uma função

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

codigo:

```
def editar (self, event=None):
    ob = self.buffer(opcao=2)
    if (ob[1] == None):
        return
    elif (ob[0] == None):
        return

    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()

    for o in self.lista:
        if (ob[0].codigo.upper() == o.codigo):
            #solicita a certeza do usuário quanto à edição
            v = askyesnocancel('Primeira rodada',
                               message='Voce tem certeza?\n'+
                               str(ob[1].semestre) + 
                               '\n'+ob[1].nome_completo.upper() + 
                               '\n'+ob[1].requisitos.upper() +
                               '\n'+str(ob[1].horas) +
                               '\n'+ob[1].estado_atual.upper() +
                               '.')
            if (v):
                dic = Disciplina(ob[1].semestre,
                                 o.codigo,
                                 ob[1].nome_completo.upper(),
                                 ob[1].horas,
                                 ob[1].requisitos.upper(),
                                 ob[1].estado_atual.upper())
                ind = lista.index(o)
                self.lista.pop(ind)
                self.lista.insert(ind, dic)

            break
```

Esse código é responsável pela edição de um objeto Disciplina , no qual ele simplesmente retira o objeto da lista e insere um similar na mesma posição.

Tudo aqui funciona perfeitamente bem. Mas a janela que detalha o objeto e contém o botão que chama por essa função permanece aberta. Sendo que ela deveria chamar essa função e fechar a janela pra voltar pra janela inicial, que é uma lista de todos os objetos.

A função que chama pela função acima:

```
def detalha (self, event=None, opcao='Editar'):
    self.janela.iconify() #minimiza a janela principal

    if (not 'adiciona' in opcao.lower()):
        item = self.listar.get(self.listar.curselection()[0])
        t = ler.achaMat(item.split(' ')[1][:6], self.lista)[1]
        det = Det(t.semestre, t.codigo, t.nome_completo,
                  t.horas, t.requisitos, t.estado_atual, opcao)
        det.janela.wm_protocol("WM_TAKE_FOCUS", det.imprime)
    else:
        det = Det(tp=opcao) #tp é o que será mostrado no botao


    if ('edita' in opcao.lower()):
        det.botao.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.editar)
    elif ('exclui' in opcao.lower()):
        det.botao.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.excluir)
    elif ('adiciona' in opcao.lower()):
        det.botao.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.adiciona)

    #Mostra a janela principal e reseta a lista 
    det.janela.bind("<Destroy>", self.reseta)
```

Antes que perguntem, o botao chama a função acao(self, event=None) e no final dela tem o chamado pra outra função self.fecha() que tem como código:

```
   def fecha (self, event=None):
       self.janela.destroy()
```

Comment: Já tentou chamar `self.fecha()` antes do `return` (se tiver) na função `self.editar`?

Comment: Nessas funções eu não chamo nenhum return. Os return são somente pra caso de erro. Não fazem nada a mais.

Eu tentei fazer qualquer coisa pra interagir informações entre janelas (são 4: principal, busca, percurso e detalhe), mas o jeito mais fácil foi salvar em um arquivo qualquer (buffer.txt) e carregar logo depois por uma outra função qualquer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu resolvi parcialmente, simplesmente colocando a janela que deveria fechar como parâmetro. Assim jogo direto no root e não preciso de nada extra. Agora é outro.

```
def editar (self, event=None, jan = None):
    ob = self.buffer(opcao=2)
    if (ob[1] == None):
        return
    elif (ob[0] == None):
        return
    print (ob[0].__dict__,"\n",
           ob[1].__dict__,"\n")

    if (jan != None):
        root = jan
    else:
        root = Tk()
        root.withdraw()

    mensagem = ('Voce tem certeza?\n\nModificacoes:'+
                str(ob[0].semestre) + "=>" + str(ob[1].semestre) + "\n"+
                ob[0].nome_completo + "=>" + ob[1].nome_completo + "\n"+
                ob[0].requisitos + "=>" + ob[1].requisitos + "\n"+
                str(ob[0].horas) + "=>" + str(ob[1].horas) + "\n"+
                ob[0].estado_atual+ "=>" + ob[1].estado_atual
                )

    v = askyesnocancel('Primeira rodada',
                           message=mensagem)

    dic = Disciplina(ob[1].semestre,
                     o.codigo,
                     ob[1].nome_completo.upper(),
                     ob[1].horas,
                     ob[1].requisitos.upper(),
                     ob[1].estado_atual.upper())

    if (v):
        ind = self.lista.index(ob[0])
        self.lista.pop(ind)
        self.lista.insert(ind, dic)

    root.cancela()
```

Acho que o problema tinha a ver com a necessidade de colocar uma janela root

```
    root = TK()
    root.withdraw()
```

pra sumir com a janela fantasma na hora de do askyesnocancel que eu tava precisando.